# Avoiding complex if statements

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I have the following function

```
const getVal = (type, a, b, val) => {
    if(type) {
        if(a && b) {
            return val;
        }else if(a) {
            return toPercent(val);
        }else{
            return undefined;
        }
    }
    return toPx(val);
}
```

is there a better way to express this? How would such a code be written in functional programming style

Comment: What does this function really do? What are those parameters? There's not a lot of other ways to express this, but maybe there's a much better way to design a solution for your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 2):

Another proposition of **early return** approach:

```
const getVal = (type, a, b, val) => {
    if(!type)
      return toPx(val);

    if(!a)
      return undefined;

    if(b)
      return val;             // (a && b)

    return toPercent(val);    // (a && !b)
}
```

This becomes a one-level comparison, without nested `if`s. 
But maybe it's harder to deconvert...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

- Instead of creating a block section, for `if(type)`, make it `if(!type)` as in that case you would return a function call.
- Instead of `a && b` and then `a`, simply check, if `a` exists, then check for `b` and return accordingly. If `a` does not exists, there is no need to check for `b`

#### Ternary operator

```js
const getVal = (type, a, b, val) => {
  if(!type) return toPx(val);
  return a ? (b ? val : toPercent(val) ) : undefined; 
}
```

#### if..else ladder

```js
const getVal = (type, a, b, val) => {
  if(!type) return toPx(val);
  if(a){
    if(b) return val;
    return toPercent(val);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't decide if I like the nested ternary operators. You can jam a lot into a line but is it as nice and readable? Checking `!type` instead is nice for sure though.

Comment: If you're uncomfortable with nesting operators, add parenthesis or indentation to make the structure clear

Comment: @Bergi you are correct... Have added parenthesis for clarity

Answer (score 0):

The else is unneeded. You can simply return at the end of checking the two prior conditions. You can also express the decisions about `a` and `b` and   more succinctly:

```
const getVal = (type, a, b, val) => {
  if(type) {
    if(a) {
      if(b) {
        return val;
      }
      return toPercent(val);
    }
    return undefined;
  }
  return toPx(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With functional programming there is a technique called currying which you can use. So you basically have a function that takes 'type' and returns a new function that takes 'val'...etc.

```
const toPercent = (val) => {
  return 'toPercent: ' + val;
};
const toPX = (val) => {
  return 'toPx: ' + val;
};

const getValByFlags = (a, b, val) => {
  if (a) {
    return b 
      ? val
      : toPercent(val);
  } 
  return undefined;
}; 

const getValByType = (type) => {
  if (!type) return toPX;
  return (val) => {
    return (a, b) => {
      return getValByFlags(a, b, val);
    };
  };
};


let a = getValByType('a')(3)(true, true);
let b = getValByType()(3);
let c = getValByType('a')(3)(true, false);
let d = getValByType('a')(3)(false, false);
```

or generically

```
let getVal = getValByType(type);
let getValByConditions = getVal(val);
let resVal = type 
  ? getValByConditions(cond1, cond2)
  : getValByConditions;
```

Comment: Yes I know that this is a bit complex, but the question was asking for functional programming and I just wanted to show how to currying it =)

Comment: I guess the real advantage here is that you're splitting it up in smaller functions - which is the main idea in functional programming. Currying can reduce overhead by passing arguments through, but that doesn't help a lot in this case.

Comment: Maybe not and maybe you are right but I do not like to create a function named 'getVal' that takes 4 args in its signature. Then the function is to complex.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator. Something like this:

```
return type? ( a&&b ? val : ( a?  toPercent(val) : undefined )) : toPx(val);
```

```js
const toPercent=(val)=>{
  return 'toPercent';
}
const toPx=(val)=>{
  return 'toPx';
}
const getVal = (type, a, b, val) => {
    return type? (a && b? val :( a ?  toPercent(val) : undefined)) : toPx(val); 
}
console.log(getVal('type',0,0,100));
console.log(getVal('type',1,0,100));
console.log(getVal('type',1,2,100));
```